# can I place popup.php instead of popup.html on Google extension?

Tags: php, google-chrome

Thanks! I just downloaded a hello world sample file, and realised it's just a HTML and JS script.

Can I replace the popup.html by a popup.php and include PHP code?

thanks!

Comment: Nope. It must be an HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No you can't . 
   Why ?
   Because PHP will require a webserver  or (php framework) to run . so .php file will not be run by chrome.

Comment: but i will be able to import a js file that acces to my server, will that be best solution?

Comment: yes. What I prefer I injects Iframe and load content using javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it with iframe and remote popup.php ;]

here is my popup.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Project: Example</h1>
<h3>Under Construction</h3>
<img src="<?= 'http://myvegaslimo.com/images/simpsons-under-construction.jpg' ?>" alt="under construction"></img></center>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is popup.html:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/chrome-extension/Example/popup.php" width="640" height="580" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```